# Postfix with Dovecot on Ubuntu 20.04 postfix/mail fatal: no sasl authentication mechanisms

Tags: postfix, dovecot, sasl

Here's the output of doveconf -n:

```
# 2.3.7.2 (3c910f64b): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.5.7.2 ()
# OS: Linux 5.17.5-x86_64-linode154 x86_64 Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS 
# Hostname: mail.servicemouse.com
doveconf: Error: t_readlink(/var/run/dovecot/dovecot.conf) failed: readlink() failed: No such file or directory
auth_debug = yes
auth_mechanisms = plain login
auth_verbose = yes
disable_plaintext_auth = no
mail_debug = yes
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
mail_privileged_group = mail
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date index ihave duplicate mime foreverypart extracttext
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix = 
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
plugin {
  sieve = file:~/sieve;active=~/.dovecot.sieve
}
protocols = " imap lmtp sieve pop3 submission"
service auth {
  unix_listener private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
}
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/<host>/fullchain.pem
ssl_dh = # hidden, use -P to show it
ssl_key = # hidden, use -P to show it
submission_relay_host = 127.0.0.1
submission_relay_ssl = starttls
submission_relay_trusted = yes
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
```

Here's the output of postconf -n:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
compatibility_level = 2
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = $myhostname, mail.servicemouse.com, localhost.servicemouse.com, , localhost
myhostname = mail.servicemouse.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.servicemouse.com/fullchain.pem
smtp_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.servicemouse.com/privkey.pem
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_service = smtpd
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.servicemouse.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.servicemouse.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_domains = site1.com, site2.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Answer (score 1):

> /var/run/dovecot/dovecot.conf) failed: readlink() failed: No such file
> or directory

Dovecot is not running. It would usually place a reference to the effective configuration there, that is why doveconf is showing this error.

Try to start it and review relevant logs to see why.

Comment: Error: service(submission-login): listen(*, 587) failed: Address already in use

Comment: I suspect you have both the Dovecot submission server and Postfix submission service attempting to listen on the same port on all interfaces. Depending on whether you actually *want* the Dovecot service, configure separate interface/port binding, or disable it.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the path for the auth listener specified in your dovecot config is placed in a location to which postfix doesn't have access (as the path must be inside the chroot of postfix) - try to use the absolute path:

```
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
}
```

Comment: I made that change and restarted dovecot: warning: SASL: Connect to private/auth failed: Connection refused mail postfix/smtpd[7416]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms

Comment: Could you further comment out the postfix parameter `smtpd_sasl_service` to reset the value to default?

Answer (score 0):

I got dovecot running by editing 10-master.conf and under service auth I set the unix_listener to /var/spool/postfix/private/auth

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem after disabled ipv6. The solution for me was to modify  in /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf the following line:

```
#listen = *, ::
listen = *
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/566478)